# The photo does not show up with image_picker- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I cant handle with **image_picker**. When I select a photo, I should see the photo instead of the avatar icon, but I don't know why it doesn't work that way. I'm new in flutter and maybe it should be solved in a different way.

The *orange circle should stay and the icon should change*, any advice will be great for me

```
 Widget _avatar() {
   return const CircleAvatar(
       radius: 83,
  backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    radius: 80,
    child: Icon(Icons.person_outline, size: 60, color: Colors.orange),
  ),
);
}

File? _image;
final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getImage() async {
  final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 1800, maxHeight: 1800);

setState(() {
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
  } else {
    print('No image selected.');
  }
});
}

Future getCameraImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
  source: ImageSource.camera,
  maxWidth: 1800,
  maxHeight: 1800,
);

setState(() {
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
  } else {
    print('No image selected.');
  }
});
}

void _showPicker(BuildContext context) {
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext bc) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(Icons.photo_size_select_large_sharp),
                  title: new Text('Photo Library'),
                  onTap: () {
                    getImage();
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }),
              ListTile(
                leading: new Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                title: new Text('Camera'),
                onTap: () {
                  getCameraImage();
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
}

Widget _changeAvatarButton(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: [
  CircleAvatar(
  radius: 83,
  backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      child: _image == null ? _avatar() : Image.file(_image!),
    ),
    CustomButtonText(
        onPressed: () {
          _showPicker(context);
        },
        title: 'photo',
        textColor: Colors.teal),
  ],
);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Your CircleAvtar widget with the below one and if you don't want to show the orange circle then set the backgroundColor: _image == null ? Colors.orange : Colors.transparent.

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 83,
  backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
  child: _image == null
      ? _avatar()
      : ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(83),
          child: Image.file(
            _image!,
            height: 160, // Change the size up or down accordingly border radius
            width: 160, // Change the size up or down accordingly border radius
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )),
),
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer, I changed it as U said and still the same error:[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(multiple_request, Cancelled by a second request, null, null)

Comment: I select an image, but when selected in the terminal it shows that it has not been selected, and doesnt apper image

Comment: Make sure you allowed the permission of storage/photos maybe it's cause the issue of image selection @azeter09

Answer (score 1):

It looks all fine with the state update and the image picking. What you should be paying attention at is the async functions, because you need to wait for the images before updating your widgets, and `getCameraImage()` and `getImage()` are a `Future`. Check if adding `await` solves the problem.

```
ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(Icons.photo_size_select_large_sharp),
                  title: new Text('Photo Library'),
                  onTap: () async {
                    await getImage();
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }),
              ListTile(
                leading: new Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                title: new Text('Camera'),
                onTap: () async {
                  await getCameraImage();
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Than appear : Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(multiple_request, Cancelled by a second request, null, null)

Comment: That happens when you don't choose an image right?

Comment: When I was trying to use image_picker, when I canceled the image selection, I always got the same error, so I opted for file_picker instead.

Comment: Basically if you don't choose any images and go back, image_picker keeps waiting for you to choose an image, and when you click again you get the multiple_request exception.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! I select an image, but when selected in the terminal it shows that it has not been selected